# What are the unit testing frameworks available in java?

Tags: java, unit-testing

What are the technologies out there? (I only know of JUnit)
What is the most popular? 
Can you please explain the pros/cons of each?

Comment: some list is here - http://java-source.net/open-source/testing-tools

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**JUnit** and **TestNG** are the main unit test frameworks.

Comparison can be found here - http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-vs-testng-comparison

I've used JUnit in most places I've worked, it seems to be the standard, but there are some nice things in TestNG.

I've used the following in combination with JUnit to facilitate testing:

- **Mockito** for mocking objects - http://code.google.com/p/mockito/
- **Hamcrest** assertions for more readable assertions - http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/
- **Twip** for parameterized testing, the JUnit stuff isn't the greatest, in fact TestNG does this better as well - http://twip.sourceforge.net/

Comment: IBM source link is broken, Please correct the URL. It has - at the end. I tried editing the answer but couldn't save it.

Comment: @Jon Its been an old answer now, technologies might have changed in this 8 years. Can you tell me which is the best unit testing frameworks for java specially for restful web services these days?

Comment: Any updates on the latest ones?

Answer (score 7):

JUnit and [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) are the most popular. JUnit being the de-facto standard, and TestNG providing some extra features.

Comment: Hence the NG - "Next Generation".

Comment: Can you answer to my question on @Jon answer?

Comment: Any updates on the latest ones?

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of "add-on" framework for specific kinds of testing, typically these depend on JUnit. Examples:

- [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) - for testing code that accesses a database
- [JFCUnit](http://jfcunit.sourceforge.net/) - for testing Swing apps
- [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) - for testing web apps

Comment: Can you answer to my question on @Jon answer?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: you don't need any special framework to unit test RESTful webservices, since with JAX-RS those are just regular java classes with some annotations, and the unit test can simply call the endpoint methods exactly the same way you would unit test any other class.

Comment: so which is the best option for a new project, testng or junit? Or any other option.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: whatever your team is familiar with, I'd say.

Comment: Actually we are exploring different frameworks for a fresh project, so we want to go with the best one. That's why I am asking which one is going to be the best option?

Comment: Any updates on the latest ones?

Answer (score 4):

Heres is a list

1. JUnit
2. Cactus
3. StrutsTestCase
4. JFCUnit
   10 javascript framework to download
5. TestNG
6. jMock
7. Grinder
8. Jetif
9. Unitils
10. p-unit
11. XMLUnit
12. Ejb3Unit
13. FEST-Swing
14. Ripplet
15. Feed4JUnit
16. Jubula functional testing tools
17. JsTestDriver
18. Citrus Testframework
    19.JBehave
19. JCrawler – load testing framework

List [Source](http://www.ssiddique.info/best-java-unit-testing-frameworks-tools.html)

Comment: Any updates on the latest ones?

Answer (score 3):

You can find good comparison between JUnit and TestNG here:

http://hi.baidu.com/auraro816/blog/item/efe0574d03db6df4d72afc9f.html

if you have time to listen podcast try with Basement coders -Episode 21 – Interview with Cedric Beust creator of testNG

Comment: Very ugly formatted page...

Comment: Link to baidu.com is dead.

Comment: Any updates on the latest ones?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from all the listing above, You can include selenium as well. This is widely used in industry for Java UI testing.

Comment: Selenium is a tool not a framework I suppose.

Comment: Any updates on the latest ones?